# How to pass a text from a div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to pass some text from an editable div to an uneditable div, onclick.
This is the result:

https://jsfiddle.net/8u5t0t1h/

HTML:

```
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>
<div id='casella'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#faketxt {
-moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
-webkit-appearance: textarea;
border: 1px solid gray;
font: medium -moz-fixed;
font: -webkit-small-control;
height: 28px;
overflow: auto;
padding: 2px;
resize: both;
width: 400px;
}

#casella{
width: 150px;
height: 300px;
font-size: 8px;
border-style: solid;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$("body").on("click", "#btn", function(){
    var primo = document.getElementById(faketxt);
var secondo = document.getElementById(casella);
secondo.val(primo).text();
})
```

How can I do it in the right way? The element that I have to pass the text has to be strictly a div and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your ids must be quoted. For example, `var primo = document.getElementById("faketxt");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using javascript, the solution is to apply `textContent` method.

**The textContent property sets or returns the textual content of the specified node, and all its descendants.**

```
$("body").on("click", "#btn", function(){
    var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
    var secondo = document.getElementById('casella');
    secondo.textContent=primo.textContent;
});
```

Here is solution using jquery  `.text()` function.

```
$("body").on("click", "#btn", function(){
    var primo = $('#faketxt');
    var secondo = $('#casella');
    secondo.text(primo.text());
});
```

```js
$("body").on("click", "#btn", function(){
    var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
    var secondo = document.getElementById('casella');
    secondo.textContent =primo.textContent;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>
<div id='casella'></div>
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8u5t0t1h/3/).

Comment: I tried but It doesn't work... Can you make a jsfiddle? maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

When you have JQuery then why mixing with JavaScript?

```
$("body").on("click", "#btn", function(){
     var primo = $("#faketxt");
     var secondo = $("#casella");
     secondo.text(primo.text());
})
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8u5t0t1h/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, use jQuery: Note that val() is only appropriate for form elements. Note that I'm using the `html()` function here, since a `contenteditable` allows for HTML elements to be mixed into the text.

```js
$("body").on("click", "#btn", function() {
  $('#casella').html($('#faketxt').html());
});
```

```css
#faketxt {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font: medium -moz-fixed;
  font: -webkit-small-control;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  resize: both;
  width: 400px;
}
#casella {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>
<div id='casella'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `text()` method of jQuery.

I have created [a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdaKJq) for you. Equivalent jsfiddle is at the end of this answer.

Also a general tip for you. Use single quotes or double quotes only. You were mixing single quotes and double quotes in your html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').on('click', '#btn', function() {
    var fakeText = $('#faketxt');
    var casellaElement = $('#casella');
    casellaElement.text(fakeText.text());
  })
});
```

```css
#faketxt {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font: medium -moz-fixed;
  font: -webkit-small-control;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  resize: both;
  width: 400px;
}

#casella {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
<button id="btn">OK</button>
<div id="casella"></div>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I have added the equivalent jsifddle code in here. Thank you for the tip :)